# Linux how to start "sftp-server"?

Tags: linux, sftp, openssh, rhel, sshd

I'm not very familiar with it but there is installed `openssh/sftp-server` (by a vendor before) on `RHEL` and it was well running before i reboot the server. Then when i check after rebooted:

```
# ps aux | grep ftp
```

No `sftp` is running but `sshd` is.

So how do i do to have this `sftp` running please?

Comment: Is this simple & straight forward question considered to be closed???

Comment: this question is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 12):

You only need to add the following line to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

or

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: I already have this line in `sshd_config` file but it is still not running. How do you restart or reload the service?

Answer (score 2):

sftp subsystem is started on demand if it is enabled in the configuration file of openssh. Check the configuration file (near the end of it) to see whether sftp subsystem is enabled and whether the path to sftp executable is correct.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to start only sftp server , without the all the ssh server ? How ?

Comment: @ransh this question is not programming-related and is off-topic. Also, asking questions in comments, if those questions are not related to the answer itself, is not a good practice. Instead you are welcome to create a new question (but on the proper site).

Comment: thanks for the comment, I will act accordingly, Regards.